# Pause Menu is "moving down" & improving the code

Tags: libgdx

I have a problem with my pause screen. I made a simple Splash screen, followed by the main menu, where you can start or end the game, followed by a random picture. If the user presses Esc it switches to the pause screen, which is very similar to the main menu. Only difference is that it doesn't generate a new picture if the user clicks on "Continue", instead it just renders the game screen again. But if I press Esc after continuing again, the pause menu appears lower on the screen than it should. If I repeat pressing Continue and then Escape, the buttons eventually moved out of the displayed screen. I didn't find a solution yet, so I made an account here, since this site helped me a lot so far.
Furthermore I want to know if there are things I could improve. I just started with libGDX, so there probably are a lot of things I could've done better, and I want to know that. SO if you have a few improvements, I would be glad to read them :)!

This is the code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;

public class GameScreen implements Screen{

    private Texture[] monsterTextures = {new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Ressources/DemonHunter.jpg")), new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Ressources/WingedDemon.jpg")),
                                        new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Ressources/Viking.jpg")), new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Ressources/DemonWarrior.jpg"))};
    private Image[] monsterImages = {new Image(monsterTextures[0]), new Image(monsterTextures[1]), new Image(monsterTextures[2]), new Image(monsterTextures[3])};
    private Stage gameStage = new Stage(), pauseStage = new Stage();
    private Table table = new Table();
    private Skin menuSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/menuSkin.json"),
                            new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("skins/menuSkin.pack")));
    private TextButton buttonContinue = new TextButton("Continue", menuSkin),
                       buttonExit = new TextButton("Exit", menuSkin);
    private Label title = new Label ("Game", menuSkin);
    private int randomMonster;

    public static final int GAME_RUNNING = 0;
    public static final int GAME_PAUSING = 1;
    public static final int GAME_PAUSED = 2;
    private int gamestatus = 0;

    @Override
    public void show() {

        randomMonster = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((3-0) + 1));
        gameStage.addActor(monsterImages[randomMonster]);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)) pauseGame();

        if(gamestatus == GAME_RUNNING) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            gameStage.act();
            gameStage.draw();
        }

        if(gamestatus == GAME_PAUSING) {
            buttonContinue.addListener(new ClickListener(){
                public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
                    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                    gamestatus = GAME_RUNNING;
                }
            });
            buttonExit.addListener(new ClickListener(){
                public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                    Gdx.app.exit();
                }
            });

            table.add(title).padBottom(40).row();
            table.add(buttonContinue).size(150, 60).padBottom(20).row();
            table.add(buttonExit).size(150, 60).padBottom(20).row();
            table.setFillParent(true);
            pauseStage.addActor(table);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(pauseStage);

            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            pauseStage.act();
            pauseStage.draw();
            gamestatus = GAME_PAUSED;
        }

        if(gamestatus == GAME_PAUSED) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            pauseStage.act();
            pauseStage.draw();
        }
        }



    public void pauseGame() {
        gamestatus = GAME_PAUSING;

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        pauseGame();

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        for(int i = 0; i < monsterTextures.length; i++) {
            monsterTextures[i].dispose();
        }
        gameStage.dispose();
        pauseStage.dispose();
        menuSkin.dispose();
    }

}
```

Thanks, Joshflux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your render() method is doing things it shouldn't. Like creating the clickListener and also adding buttons to the table (and possibly some other items in there).

The render method gets called every "frame". You don't want to be recreating this, say 60 times a second. You want to do it once (like when you create the particular screen) and then just draw (render) it every frame.

Restructure your code to do the "Creation" stuff once. The render() method should just draw it. I think you continually adding items to your table each frame may be what is causing the buttons to move off the screen.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I made one more GAME_... variable, so that the creation is done once and than this condition is left. It did the trick :).